# Repeatedly multiplying by numbers taken from a uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-walk

Motivation: In a software project I know well, for testing purposes, the evolution of a particular price is simulated by repeatedly multiplying by a random number picked between $0.995$ and $1.005$.

Let us formalize this.

Let $(X_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of ***independent*** random variables, each with a (continuous) uniform distribution in $[0.995,1.005]$,
$$X_i \sim U([0.995,1.005])$$
For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we define the random variable
$$P_n = \prod_{i=1}^n X_i$$
which represents the price at day $n$.

I call for a proof of the fact that the price tends to zero as $n$ grows without bound. One way of formalizing this is to define a map $P_\infty$ by:
$$P_\infty : \omega\mapsto\begin{cases}
\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n(\omega),&\text{if the limit exists} \\
\text{undefined},&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
where $\omega$ is an abstract outcome of the probability space. Then can you show that $P_\infty$ is defined *almost everywhere* (and is measurable) so that we can see $P_\infty$ as a random variable, and prove that the distribution of $P_\infty$ is that of a constant, i.e.
$$\mathrm{Pr}(P_\infty = 0) = 1$$
where $\mathrm{Pr}$ is the probability measure?

---

**Bonus question:** One way to "fix" the issue with the price going towards zero, would be to change the distribution of the $X_i$ into $X_i=\exp(D_i)$ where the $D_i$ are independent and all distributed $D_i \sim U([-0.005,0.005])$.

However, suppose for the purpose of the exercise, that we were required to keep the $X_i$ uniformly distributed, and could only change the lower endpoint, into, say, $\alpha$. So now
$$X_i \sim U([\alpha,1.005])$$
and otherwise everything is as before. For too low values of $\alpha$, $P_\infty$ will be $0$ as before. But for higher values of $\alpha$, it appears that $P_n$ would (almost surely) go to $+\infty$ instead.

So the bonus question is, what "Goldilocks" value of $\alpha$ should be chosen so that $P_\infty$ is neither $0$, nor $+\infty$?

Comment: Use the law of large numbers for $\log P_n$.

Comment: @zhoraster That sounds right! If $X_i \sim U([\alpha, 1.005])$, is it true that we have $$E(\log X_i) = \int_\alpha^{1.005} \frac{\log x}{1.005 - \alpha} dx?$$ We know an antiderivative for $\log x$ and can plug in. Then set expression equal to zero (we want the expectation of $\log X_i$ to be zero) and solve for $\alpha$. From that I get (using numerical method): $$\alpha = 0.995008319483677112\ldots$$ Could that be correct?

Comment: It does seem correct to me.